# How to add seconds in a datetime

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I need to add seconds in YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS. My code works perfectly for one data point but not for the whole set. The data.txt consists of 7 columns and around 200 rows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt',sep='\t',header=None)
a = np.array(list(df[0]))
b = np.array(list(df[1]))
c = np.array(list(df[2]))
d = np.array(list(df[3]))
e = np.array(list(df[4]))
f = np.array(list(df[5]))
g = np.array(list(df[6]))
t1=datetime(year=a, month=b, day=c, hour=d, minute=e, second=f)
t = t1 + timedelta(seconds=g)
print(t)
```

Comment: The datetime object constructor only takes scalar arguments - is this code actually working? How does your df look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameter `names` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for new columns names in first step and then convert first 5 columns to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and add seconds converted to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
names = ["year","month","day","hour","minute","second","new"]
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt',sep='\t',names=names)

df['out'] = pd.to_datetime(df[names]) +  pd.to_timedelta(df["new"], unit='s')
```

Answer (score 0):

use `apply` with `axis=1` to apply a function to every row of the dataframe.

```
df.apply(lambda x: datetime(year=x[0],
                            month=x[1],
                            day=x[2],
                            hour=x[3],
                            minute=x[4],
                            second=x[5]) + timedelta(seconds=int(x[6])) , axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

- generating dataset
- simple to do as *pandas series*

```
s = 20
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.random.randint(2015,2020,s),np.random.randint(1,12,s),np.random.randint(1,28,s),
             np.random.randint(0,23,s), np.random.randint(0,59,s), np.random.randint(0,59,s),
             np.random.randint(0,200,s)]).T,
            columns=["year","month","day","hour","minute","second","add"])

pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,["year","month","day","hour","minute","second"]]) + df["add"].apply(lambda s: pd.Timedelta(seconds=s))
```

#### without using apply()

```
pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,["year","month","day","hour","minute","second"]]) + pd.to_timedelta(df["add"], unit="s")
```